# Positivity of semigroup $(P_t)_{t\geq0}$ implies its contractivity, $\| P_tf\| \leq \|f\|$

Tags: banach-spaces, matrix-exponential, semigroup-of-operators, contraction-operator

Let $\Omega$ be a Polish space, denote $E = (C_b(\Omega),\|\cdot\|)$ be the Banach space of continuous and bounded functions with the usual supremum norm. A family $(P_t)_{t\geq 0} $ of linear operators on $E$ is called a semigroup iff

1. $P_0 = I$, the identity map on $E$,
2. The map $t\mapsto P_t$ is continuous in the sense: $\forall f \in E$, $t\mapsto P_tf$ is a continuous map from $\mathbb R^+$ to $E$,
3. $P_{t+s} = P_tP_s, \forall t,s \geq 0$,

A semigroup is called Markov if in addition,

4. $P_t1 = 1$, (1 is the function that takes only value 1),
5. $P_t$ is positive, i.e, if $f\geq 0$ then $P_tf \geq 0$.

Questions:

A) Prove that if $P$ is Markov then it is contractive, i.e,  $\| P_tf\| \leq \| f\| $?

B) Let $A$ be a positive bounded linear operator on $E$, and that $\| A \| \leq 1$ (in operator norm), $A1 =1$. Let $\lambda >0 $. Verify that
$$ P_t := e^{t\lambda(A-I)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{ n!}(A-I)^n $$
is a Markov operator.

Context: I encountered A) in a lecture note, which I don't know how to prove and begin with. For B), I can only verify 1,3,4. I don't know how to verify the continuity (2.) and also, I suspect that it is differentiable as well. For 5., I have tried to prove the finite sum $H_N = \sum^N_{n=0}...$ has the property

$$\| H_Nf \| \leq \| f\|,$$

for $N=0,1,2,3$, but I don't know quite how to do it inductively for all $N$.

I hope to get a detailed treatment of 2. and its differentiability as well if possible (for me to learn this kind of calculus) and **only some hints** on A) and how to prove 5 inductively. Thank you in advance :D.

Comment: For (A), the hint is that $\|f\|-f\geq 0$. 
For (B.2) note first show that use the positivity of $A$ to show that $\|(A-I)\|\leq 1$. Use this to check that $|P_tf-P_sf|\leq |(t-s)||(A-I)f|+\|f\|\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^n(t^{n}-s^{n})}{n!}$. You should now be able to show that as $s\to t$ the RHS goes to zero. You can show the differentiability as well doing the same argument a little more carefully.

Comment: I still don't see why $ \|(A-I)f\| \leq \|f\| $...., I tried showing $ A(f-\|f\|) -f \leq -f$ but this shows nothing. For B.2, that is exactly where I got stuck (though I think we don't need $\| A-I \| \leq 1$ to show continuity)...

Comment: In fact, I just noticed that we have $P_{t+s} = P_sP_t$, so differentiability will come if we prove the differentiability at 0, which is okay for me now. Can you help me with 5., and why $\| A -I \| \leq 1$?

Comment: You are right that you possibly don't need to show that $\|A-I\|\leq 1$. Rather, you can get by triangle inequality $\|A-I\|\leq 2$ which would still yield the continuity using the same argument. To see that $\|(A-I)\|\leq 1$, I would use spectral theorem or something along that line, but I guess it requires some more work.
For (5), I would show that $e^{t\lambda (A-I)}=e^{-\lambda t}e^{t\lambda A}$. Since $A$ is positive, so are $A^{n}$ for all $n$. It follows that $e^{\lambda t A}f\geq 0$ for all $f\geq 0$.